# SmartScreen does ignore EV Code Signing Certificate

Tags: c#, code-signing-certificate, smartscreen

Since almost 2 years we do distribute a little ClickOnce Application, created with Visual Studio 2015/2017.
 
To solve the Windows SmartScreen issues, our company did buy a EV Code Signing Certificate at Comodo (now Sectigo) which immediately should establish reputation and eliminate installation hassles.
It did work perfectly....
However some days ago, we did find out that SmartScreen is throwing warnings again, like if there would be no certificate.
Is there a general change in the way EV Code Signing Certificates are beeing evaluated by SmartScreen?
Or is it something individual, related to Building options within Visual Studio?
Installation file: https://webapi.aspsms.com/download/setup.exe

Comment: Your issue appears to be the same one described in this Security.SE question: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/139520 I am uncertain about copy-and-pasting the answer from there, so I'll just leave this comment instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it's not the same. We did buy an EV (Extended Validation) exactly for that reason. The Certificate, mentioned in the other thread, is a "normal" Code Signing Certificate, *without* Extended Validation.

Comment: I suspect that the new Sectigo root certificate is not yet in the Microsoft Trusted Root Program. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/trusted-root/participants-list

Comment: Please disregard that; I finally found the Sectigo cert on the list by its SHA256 thumbprint. Okay, I admit it. I'm out of ideas. If anyone cares to know, the SHA256 calculated by OpenSSL is: 52F0E1C4E58EC629291B60317F074671B85D7EA80D5B07273463534B32B40234

Comment: We also bought an EV from Sectigo and can confirm this is still an issue.  Contacted Sectigo and they're aware of this issue and they already contacted Microsoft. Till then this EV is worth as much as a normal code signing certificate I guess.

Comment: I can confirm that Comodo EV Code signing still doesn't work. I bought it two days ago. Smartscreen is still there and they KNOW about issue. Despite this it's still possible to buy it on their webiste.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign and verify your binaries externally using 3rd party tool like Digicert.
[download and instructions](https://www.digicert.com/code-signing/digicert-certificate-utility-to-sign-code.htm)

So, better to try this option as well. If it work then the issue is on your Visual Studio.